$k(x)$ is finitely generated as a $k$-algebra, can I view $k(x)/k$ as a field extension?
I try to prove that the finite dimensional division algebra $\Delta$ over algerbaically closed field $k$ is $k$ itself.
First, we take $0\neq x\in\Delta$ then consider $k(x)\subset\Delta$ as subalgebra (as finitely generated $k$-module) since $D$ is finite dimensional as vector space over $k$, then $k(x)/k$ view as a field extension(?) is a finite extension. Then $k(x)/k$ algebraic, since $k$ is a algerbaically closed field. then $x\in k$.
My question is $k(x)$ is finitely generated as a $k$-algebra, can I view  $k(x)/k$ as a field extension? (I confuse since $x$ is not in field extension of $k$.)

You need to prove that $k(x)$ is a field. This requires using the fact that $\Delta$ is a division algebra, together with the observation that $k(x)$ is commutative.
